# In R: Avoid duplicates in selection from many rows

Tags: r, random, duplicates, selection, coding-efficiency

**Summary**: I have an array of 10 rows and 4 columns filled with numbers. I select one number from each row and want to avoid duplicates in the selection.

**Elaborate**:
I have a grid of 100*100 cells. In that grid are 10 cells that contain a "person". In an iterative process I want to make the persons "walk around" in the grid, but I do not want to occur that two persons are in the same cell at the same time.

I have a vector that describes the positions of the 10 persons. It contains the cell numbers with a person. These positions are counting across all rows and columns (i.e. ranges from 1:10000). For example: Position 234 would be in the 3rd row, 34th column).

```
Positions<-sample(1:10000,10)   #Initial positions
```

What I did is to first make an array of the surrounding cells of each person (up, right, down, left) giving 4 positions for each person:

```
Surroundings<-array(c(Positions+100,Positions+1,Positions-100,Positions-1),dim=c(10,4))
```

I then take a random direction from each of the rows in `Surroundings` into vector `PosNew`. It is this last vector in which I want to avoid duplicates.

I could repeat the random selection process of `PosNew` until it has no duplicates, but this could take very long. There are probably more efficient ways to do this.

For simplicity sake, let's assume that persons do not walk off the grid and no other errors occur.

My script:

```
Positions<-sample(1:10000,10)   #Initial positions

for(i in 1:50) {
 Surroundings<-array(c(Positions+100,Positions+1,Positions-100,Positions-1),dim=c(10,4))
 PosNew<-Surroundings[cbind(1:10,sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE))] 
 Dups<-length(which(duplicated(PosNew)==TRUE))
 Positions<-PosNew
}
```

I am looking for a way to check for duplicates in the selected new positions and make sure that `Dups` is never above zero. Any suggestions are welcome, including suggestions to make the code faster/more efficient.

Added: What could I do when at some point one or more of the persons really cannot move to an empty cell, because all 4 sides are occupied? I want that person to stay in its original cell. How to code that?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Are you aware of a common name for this problem (i.e. "Traveling Salesman" or "Turán's brick factory")? This is an interesting challenge to tackle but it seems general enough that it has to have been researched extensively, even if an `R` solution hasn't been explicitly documented.

Comment: Could you explain how minimizing travel distance and/or minimizing the number of crossings overlap with my problem?

Comment: There is no overlap -- I just gave those as two examples of well known, named math problems. Many excellent algorithms have been proposed that tackle those two problems, and the solutions can quickly be implemented in the language of choice. I was simply curious if there might be already be some general solutions proposed to this problem out there if one knew the right key phrase to search, hope I haven't just added confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an iterative process, where every person's move depends on the locations of others, I don't think you can do much better then moving one person and sampling the position for the next from the difference of the sets of all directions and all occupied positions (note that this adds a bit of unfairness as the first person has the most freedom to move, so to speak).

So the code would be something like this:

```
Positions <- sample(1:10000, 10)   #Initial positions

for (i in 1:50) {
  Surroundings <-
    array(c(Positions + 100, Positions + 1, Positions - 100, Positions - 1),
          dim = c(10, 4))

  # BEGIN NEW CODE
  PosNew <- numeric(10)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    # PosNew[seq_len(i-1)] is the set of occupied positions
    available <- setdiff(Surroundings[i, ], PosNew[seq_len(i-1)])
    if (length(available) != 0)
      PosNew[i] <- sample(available, 1)
    else
      PosNew[i] <- Positions[i] # stay where you are
  }
  # END NEW CODE

  Dups <- sum(duplicated(PosNew)) # shorter version - sum logical values to get a count

  Positions <- PosNew
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Smart use of 'setdiff()'. Do you think there is any way to solve this problem without introducing extra loops?

Comment: I'm not sure, because you have an iterative problem and it's not easily vectorized because you have dependence between iterations. What occurred to me originally was that you could make a matrix with all possible combinations of next positions with expand.grid for example, and then sample only from the allowed combinations (rows with no duplicate elements), but I gave this up because you'd have a million combinations to choose from and the problem would become even more complex. I don't think you'd have a speedup that way, although I didn't time anything.

Comment: OK, I'll use the extra 'for()' loop then. But I was thinking it would be faster to only loop through the duplicates. This would be a second round of selections, so it would automatically choose from the still available spots. This can at least work when the number of "persons" is small. I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Block6 that could be a good solution, it adds a bit of uncertainty as to how many times you'd have to resample the duplicates, but if they're really unlikely that version would in most cases be faster. You should try that too and see what works better, you can use microbenchmark to compare the speed of both solutions.

Comment: Yeah, and if that turns out better, you can post your solution as the answer as well, and accept that :) It could be useful for someone that comes along in the future.